# Why does ClipBoard Class have name attribute

Tags: java, clipboard

I am using the Clipboard Class in Java and I am not sure why it has 
name attribute, especially as it is passed in the constructor. For what can I use that attribute.

[Clipboard Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *guess* (having not written that class...) that's because there *might be* situations, in which you want to handle multiple Clipboards on your own, and a name is a nice way to identify a specific instance.

As a matter of fact, I've never seen it used in any other way then `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()` and in this case, `getName()` resolves to `System` (on Windows at least)

Comment: At least for windows, there are several clipboard managers on the web where you can have more than just one entry...

Comment: Entries in the Clipboard: Yes. But *different clipboards**?